# AWS SSO - "Request nameID format does not match our record"

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml, aws-sso

I'm trying to get a test app working with the AWS single sign-on service.  When I hit the SSO login url and enter my credentials, it logs in fine, but then Amazon displays the error:

`Requeest nameID format does not match our record`

[image: Requeest nameID format does not match our record]

My request contains:

`<samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" AllowCreate="true" />`

and the IdP metadata xml that Amazon comes up with for my app has a blank `<md:NameIDFormat/>` tag.  I'm guessing that has something to do with it.  However, I'm not seeing anywhere, in the Amazon UI, where the `nameIDFormat` can be specified.

My questions:

1. How/where can I specify the `nameIDFormat` that my AWS SSO app accepts?  This is assuming the blank `<md:NameIDFormat/>` is (part of the) issue.  Maybe that has nothing to do with the issue, in which case:
2. What does the above error message mean?

Comment: If your SP leveraged the meta data of AWS IdP, it would not send the `NameIDPolicy` element in the SAML AuthnRequest. I guess you are forcing the SP to send this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change NameID format at AWS SSO "Applications" page:

1. Go to AWS SSO->Applications->My App Name
2. Set `${user:subject}` as attribute value (second column) and select necessary NameID format in third column.

[image: AWS SSO->Applications->My App Name]

Once this will be done you can send a corresponding NameID format by NameIDPolicy tag:

```
<saml2p:NameIDPolicy 
        Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"/>
```

BTW : by using a NameIDPolicy tag, SP requests from IdP a corresponding NameID format (email, transient, persistent etc.). Your AWS IdP doesn't have a requested mapping and don't know what should be returned by default or what is allowed and throws an error you see.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same exact problem, spoke with Twilio's tech support and they put me on a plugin that lets you trace the SAML stuff -> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/saml-tracer/mpdajninpobndbfcldcmbpnnbhibjmch

Once I corrected my issues, nameid-format:unspecified to emailAddress it worked!

[image]